# Calculate the average of a quantity based on a primary key in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which contains the sgpa of students. I have to calculate the cgpa of these students. The student's id_no is the primary key in the csv file. The file is in the form:

```
St_id    St_name    sem_id    sgpa 
  1        abc        1        2  
  2        pqr        1        2.5
  1        abc        2        3
  2        pqr        2        3.5
  3        xzy        1        4.0
```

I now need a new column that calculates the cgpa of students. The new table should be in the form:

```
St_id    St_name   sem_id     sgpa    cgpa
  1        abc        1        2      2.5
  2        pqr        1        2.5    3.0
  1        abc        2        3      2.5
  2        pqr        2        3.5    3.0
  3        xzy        1        4.0    4.0
```

I have thousands of students like this, so I cannot calculate it manually. Can someone please suggest a way to accomplish this task in Python? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: how is cgpa calculated?

Comment: @AshishAcharya cgpa is just the average of sgpa. So if the student has 3 semesters, then (sem1sgpa+ sem2sgpa + sem3sgpa)/3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df['cgpa'] = df.groupby('St_id')['sgpa'].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
   St_id St_name  sem_id  sgpa  cgpa
0      1     abc       1   2.0   2.5
1      2     pqr       1   2.5   3.0
2      1     abc       2   3.0   2.5
3      2     pqr       2   3.5   3.0
4      3     xzy       1   4.0   4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem.. :)

Answer (score 1):

df['cgpa'] = df.apply(lambda row: df[df.St_id == row.St_id].sgpa.mean(), axi
s=1)